# Не обновляются данные

Tags: php

Привет! Столкнулся с такой проблемой: пишу редактирование настроек, но заметил что при нажатии "Сохранить" данные то меняются, но видимо не успевают обновиться в браузере. Поэтому при нажатии "Сохранить" выполняется блок редактирования и выводит "Ок", но с первого раза на странице данные не обновляются, остаются старые. Но если обновить, то все ок.

Расскажите, пожалуйста, как можно подобное решить? Пробовал `sleep`, думал может браузер не успевает обновить, но нет.

Comment: Каким образом реализовано сохранение? Ajax?

Comment: Нет, обычный POST.

Comment: 90% что вы данные на странице подгружаете до изменения. Но вообще вопрос настолько абстрактный, что, пожалуй, я выскажу свое неудовлтеворение отсутствием кода.